# How to know the ui-router is checking for the path?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am getting 404 Not Found error with my angular JS project which I am new to it.

All the states seems to be looking good but still getting the error.

I assume that Angularjs is looking in different path than I assume, but is there a way to know where ui-rotuer is looking for the paths.

Any properties available on $state to see the correct path that it is looking for?

For example in linux machines, if you type "pwd" then it displays the current directory so similarly any statement available in ui-router to know where it is looking for the corresponding paths for the URLs.?

Comment: Add a listener in your run block for state change error. See router docs.. Also if it is a server side 404 and you have html5Mode set to true make sure server side is configured for html5Mode

Comment: It did not work to me, I put the breakpoint in the listener, but getting 404 error before reaching the breakpoint by reloading the page. I disabled html5mode but still getting the error.

Comment: Doing something wrong then...there is an error object that will tell you what's wrong. Log it to your console